# check for authorization status to photo library

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to check for your app's authorization-level to the device's photo library under the new iOS 6 authorization scheme?

In other words, is there an equivalent for ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus that goes against the photo library instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
```

The docs for `ALAuthorizationStatus` show the possible values. This API only works under iOS 6.0 or later.

Comment: what should i do below iOS 6.0?

Comment: should be "ALAssetsLibrary"

Answer (score 1):

I am using this contruction:

```
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if (*stop) {
            return ;
        }
// TODO : access granted
    *stop = TRUE;
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        // TODO: User denied access. Tell them we can't do anything.
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `PHPhotoLibrary` in Swift, you should get the value of `PHAuthorizationStatus` :

```
    let authorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
```

Return values are :

```
public enum PHAuthorizationStatus : Int {  

    case notDetermined // User has not yet made a choice with regards to this application

    case restricted // This application is not authorized to access photo data.

// The user cannot change this application’s status, possibly due to active restrictions
//   such as parental controls being in place.
    case denied // User has explicitly denied this application access to photos data.

    case authorized // User has authorized this application to access photos data.
}
```